# restoring sub-graph variables fails with 'Cannot interpret feed_dict key'

Tags: python, tensorflow

The context is that I'm trying to incrementally grow a rnn autoencoder, by first training a single cell encoder/decoder then extending. I'd like to load the parameters of the preceding cells.

This code here is a minimal code where I'm investigating how to do this, and it fails with:

```
TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: The name 'save_1/Const:0' refers to a Tensor which does not exist. The operation, 'save_1/Const', does not exist in the graph.
```

**I've searched and found nothing, [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41732627/tensorflow-feed-dict-key-cannot-be-interpreted-as-tensor) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47085859/typeerror-cannot-interpret-feed-dict-key-as-tensor-the-name-save-const0-ref) are not the same problem.**

### MVCE

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:
    cell1 = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(1,name='lstm_cell1')
    cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([cell1])

    inputs = tf.random_normal((5,10,1))
    rnn1 = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell,inputs,dtype=tf.float32)
    vars0 = tf.trainable_variables()
    saver = tf.train.Saver(vars0,max_to_keep=1)
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    saver.save(sess,'./save0')

    vars0_val = sess.run(vars0)
# creating a new graph/session because it is not given that it'll be in the same session.  
with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:
    cell1 = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(1,name='lstm_cell1')
    #one extra cell
    cell2 = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(1,name='lstm_cell2')
    cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([cell1,cell2])

    inputs = tf.random_normal((5,10,1))
    rnn1 = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell,inputs,dtype=tf.float32)  
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

    # new saver with first cell variables
    saver = tf.train.Saver(vars0,max_to_keep=1)

    # fails
    saver.restore(sess,'./save0')

    # Should be the same
    vars0_val1 = sess.run(vars0)
    assert np.all(vars0_val1 = vars0_val)
```

Answer (score 0):

The mistake comes from the line,

```
saver = tf.train.Saver(vars0,max_to_keep=1)
```

if the second session. `vars0` refers to actual tensor objects that existed in the previous graph (not the current one). Saver's `var_list` requires an actual set of tensors (not strings, which I assumed would be good enough).
To make it work the second Saver object should be initialized with the corresponding tensors in the current graph. 
Something like,

```
vars0_names = [v.name for v in vars0]
load_vars = [sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name(n) for n in vars0_names]
saver = tf.train.Saver(load_vars,max_to_keep=1)
```